# Unable to unbind [Super]+[1..9] in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm currently running Ubuntu 20.04.1 with gnome 3.36.3. I've installed Terminator and mapped it to being the default terminal. I used to be able to use [Super]+[1] to have Terminator insert the terminal number in a set of windows that were bound for broadcasting. That no longer works.

Now, if I press [Super] combined with any of the number keys, it corresponds to one of my favorites on the side bar. I tried removing all of my favorites, in the hopes that it would allow the shortcut for Terminator to function, but no luck.

I've looked around the system and searched for an answer, but have not found one. I am unable to determine how to unbind [Super]+[1...9]

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These hotkeys are assigned by the Ubuntu Dock. Turn all these <kbd>Super</kbd> hotkeys off with the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys false
```

If you would wish, you can disable individual keys only, as in

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-1 ['']
```

or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-ctrl-hotkey-1 ['']
```

or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-1 ['']
```

You can reset to default settings by replacing `set` by `reset`, and omitting the final argument, for example as

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-1 ['']
```

All of these settings are also available via `dconf-editor` (not installed by default).